# I'm getting trading view's Could not find function or function reference 'tostring'

Tags: pine-script

i'm trying to build a script/indicator which gives me alerts when a specific condition is met on a specific chart and time frame, pretty simple condition here is the code :

> //@version=5
> indicator("Consecutive Candles Alert", shorttitle="CC Alert", overlay=false)
>
> Input parameters
> length = input.int(5, minval=1, title="Consecutive Candles Length")
> symbolToWatch = input.symbol("EURUSD", title="Symbol to Watch")
> timeFrameToWatch = input.timeframe("1", title="Timeframe to Watch")
>
> Calculate consecutive candles of the same direction
> isBullish = close > open
> isBearish = close < open
> consecBullish = ta.barssince(isBullish) + 1
> consecBearish = ta.barssince(isBearish) + 1
>
> Check for the condition and trigger alert
> alertCondition = (consecBullish >= length and isBearish) or (consecBearish >= length and isBullish)
> alert("Consecutive Candles Alert: " + syminfo.tickerid + " - " + tostring(timeFrameToWatch), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
>
> Plot consecutive candles count
> consecCount = alertCondition ? (isBullish ? consecBullish : consecBearish) : na
> plotshape(consecCount, title="Consecutive Candles Count", location=location.top, color=color.red, style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.white)
>
> Plot candles
> plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=isBullish ? color.new(color.green, 50) : color.new(color.red, 50))
>
> Set up alert message
> timeFrameString = "1" // Default value for 1-minute timeframe
> if timeFrameToWatch == "3"
> timeFrameString := "3"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "5"
> timeFrameString := "5"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "15"
> timeFrameString := "15"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "30"
> timeFrameString := "30"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "60"
> timeFrameString := "1H"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "D"
> timeFrameString := "1D"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "W"
> timeFrameString := "1W"
> else if timeFrameToWatch == "M"
> timeFrameString := "1M"
>
> alert_message = "Consecutive Candles Alert: " + syminfo.ticker + " " + timeFrameString + "\n" +
> "Consecutive Bullish Candles: " + tostring(consecBullish) + "\n" +
> "Consecutive Bearish Candles: " + tostring(consecBearish)
>
> Send alert to phone
> alertcondition(alertCondition, title="Consecutive Candles Alert", message=alert_message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `v5`, functions have been moved to different namespaces. The particular one you are looking for is under `str`. So, you should be using [str.tostring()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_str.tostring).

```
str.tostring(value) → series string
```

Comment: Error at 39:32 Undeclared identifier 'barstate'